# w3.css changes my custom styles

Tags: html, stylesheet

I am using the following html code with wordpress for creating tabs. I am also using a custom css which tries to modify some of the title formats.
When I remove the 4th line of the following code () my style works fine. But when I include this line my styles are changing, including the font type. How can I resolve this?

```
         <html>
         <title>W3.CSS</title>
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css"/>
         <body>

         <div class="w3-container" style="margin-top: -50px;">
           <ul class="w3-navbar w3-black">
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink w3-blue" onclick="openCity(event, 'London');">London</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris');">Paris</a></li>
             <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablink" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo');">Tokyo</a></li>
           </ul>

           <div id="London" class="w3-container w3-border city">
             <h2>London</h2>
             <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
           </div>

           <div id="Paris" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
             <h2>Paris</h2>
             <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p> 
           </div>

           <div id="Tokyo" class="w3-container w3-border city" style="display:none">
             <h2>Tokyo</h2>
             <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
           </div>
         </div>

         <script>
         function openCity(evt, cityName) {
           var i, x, tablinks;
           x = document.getElementsByClassName("city");
           for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
               x[i].style.display = "none";
           }
           tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
           for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
               tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" w3-red", "");
           }
           document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
           evt.currentTarget.className += " w3-red";
         }
         </script>
         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: "I am also using a custom css which tries to modify some of the title formats." — Not in the code you've supplied.

Comment: "when I include this line my styles are changing, including the font type. How can I resolve this?" — If you don't like the changes w3.css makes then either don't include it (it's generally best to avoid anything from W3Schools anyway) or write styles which override it. (Read up on the cascade, it's a very basic and important part of CSS).

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem and found solution

open up your w3.css file and remove styles applied globally.

like html{ //styles}

body{styles }.

just keep styles applied based on classes. 
like .w3-green{ //styles}.
w3-input{ //styles}

In your case remove lines from 1 to 37 in w3.css file then it will work fine without changing your styles